# ML - Instance-based learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am quite new to machine learning and I've been reading a book where the author describes instance-based learning as follows

> Possibly  the most    trivial form    of  learning    is  simply  to  learn   by  heart.  If  you were    to  create  a   spam    filter
>   this  way,    it  would   just    flag    all emails  that    are identical   to  emails  that    have    already been    flagged by  users
>   — not the worst   solution,   but certainly   not the best.
>
> Instead   of  just    flagging    emails  that    are identical   to  known   spam    emails, your    spam    filter  could   be
>   programmed    to  also    flag    emails  that    are very    similar to  known   spam    emails. This    requires    a   measure of
>   similarity    between two emails. A   (very   basic)  similarity  measure between two emails  could   be  to  count
>   the   number  of  words   they    have    in  common. The system  would   flag    an  email   as  spam    if  it  has many    words
>   in    common  with    a   known   spam    email.
>
> This  is  called  instance-based  learning:   the system  learns  the examples    by  heart,  then    generalizes to  new
>   cases using   a   similarity  measure

But I couldn't understand it completely as he used the words `similar` and  `identical`. I didn't understand difference. Any explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identical literally means identical - there are zero differences and it is an exact match.

The strings "aaaaa" and "aaaaa" are identical. There is no other string that can ever exist that is also identical to "aaaaa" other than itself.

Similar again is being used in the literal sense. "aaaaa" and "aaaab" are not identical, they differ by one character. But they are similar in that they share 4 out of 5 characters. There are many-many possible strings that are similar to "aaaaa".

Naively looking at the number of different characters in a string is one way to define similarity.

The trick to all instance based learning is the answering the question: how do we *explicitly* define similar for *this* application. Every application would likely benefit from different measures of similarity, though there are some common ones do exist and get re-used frequently, that doesn't mean they are optimal.